# Telegram OAuth: Content Security Policy блокирует загрузку виджета

Tags: telegram, express, безопасность, oauth

Пытаюсь прикрутить к сайту авторизацию через Telegram. Настроил и скопировал скрипт с https://core.telegram.org/widgets/login, развернул на проде через HTTPS (серт letsencrypt). Firefox ругнулся:

```
Content Security Policy: Параметры страницы заблокировали загрузку ресурса https://telegram.org/js/telegram-widget.js?15 («script-src»). bundle.js:1:281
```

Сервер работает на Express, подключил helmet, настроил заголовки следующим образом:

```
this.app.use(helmet.contentSecurityPolicy({
    defaultSrc: ["*"],
    styleSrc:   ["self", "unsafe-inline"],
    scriptSrc:  ["self", "unsafe-inline", "unsafe-eval", "telegram.org"]
}));
```

Продолжает ругаться. Что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 1):

Оказывается, в опциях метода contentSecurityPolicy указывается не сам набор нужных ограничений, а вот такая структура:

```
this.app.use(helmet.contentSecurityPolicy({
    useDefaults: true,
    directives: {
        defaultSrc: ["'self'", "oauth.telegram.org"],
        styleSrc:   ["'self'"],
        scriptSrc:  ["'self'", "'unsafe-eval'", "telegram.org"]
}}));
```

Это рабочий вариант для добавления виджета ТГ на свой сайт.